# how to send multiple messages using android smsmanager

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop sms app that can load messages and tel numbers from server and store it internally, therefore when trying to send all messages at once using loop only some of them are sent, and this is my code. please help

```
   send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            try {

                String SENT = "sent";
                String DELIVERED = "delivered";

                Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SENT);
 /*Create Pending Intents*/
                PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        getApplicationContext(), 0, sentIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent(DELIVERED);

                PendingIntent deliverPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        getApplicationContext(), 0, deliveryIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 /* Register for SMS send action */
                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        String result = "";

                        switch (getResultCode()) {

                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                result = "Transmission successful";
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                result = "Transmission failed";

                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                                result = "Radio off";
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                result = "No PDU defined";
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                                result = "No service";
                                break;
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
 /* Register for Delivery event */
                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

  /*Send SMS*/
                ArrayList<Messages> messagesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
         /* loading messages and phone into arraylist */
                messagesArrayList = db.getMessages();
                for (int i = 0; i < messagesArrayList.size() ; i++) {

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage("090" +       messagesArrayList.get(i).getPhone(), null, messagesArrayList.get(i).getBody(), sentPI,
                            deliverPI);



                }

                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
String strnum="100864445556;1004522145586;100855822557;100885222559";



Uri smsToUri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + strnum);
```

if you are getting numbers from database query then

with the help of loops

make string `strnum = num1 + ";" + num2 + ";" + num3 + ";"` so on

Comment: thank you, but I am getting telephone numbers from database query

Comment: please try to understand what I want, each recepient number and message that I want to send is different from one another, and the number of messages could be 10,1000,435

Comment: forexample the app loads 500 messages and tries to send, may be first 100 messages are sent and the rest fail, and I don't why some are sent and others not sent, please anyone who knows help me.